# How to stream a HTTP response while writing to the same stream?

Tags: c#, stream, asp.net-core-2.1

I have some the following function that formats some data into csv:

```
public static void WriteToStream(IEnumerable<MyClass> data, Stream stream)
{
   var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
   foreach(var record in data)
   {
      var line = // code that generates the csv line.
      writer.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

In my REST controller method, I'm trying to send this stream as a response. I'm trying the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCsvStream()
{
   var data = // code to get raw data.

   var stream = new MemoryStream();
   WriteToStream(data, stream);

   return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/csv");
}
```

However, I'm getting `Internal Server Error` with this code. What I would like to achieve is to continuously stream `data` as csv.

EDIT:

By the way, I'm currently doing it as below as John suggested. But, does this actually stream data or does it write all the content to response body first and then sends the final response? My understanding is it's the latter.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCsvStream()
{
   var data = // code to get raw data.

   WriteToStream(data, this.HttpContext.Response.Body);

   return this.Ok();
}
```

Comment: Just write to the response stream instead.

Comment: @John I added an edit, can you please see if that's what you meant? Does it actually stream (as in send piece by piece) or wait for all csv content to be written to the response before sending?